# Access to the provided image was forbidden even though it was uploaded from the same account

Tags: google-docs-api

Using service account, I`m trying to create a folder in root folder available to the account and upload images to created folder.

```py
async def create_folder(api, parent, name):
    return await api.as_service_account(
        drive.files.create(
            json = {
                'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                'name': name,
                'parents': [parent]
            },
        )
    )

async def upload_file(api, path, parent, name):
    return await api.as_service_account(
        drive.files.create(
            upload_file = path,
            json = {
                'name': name,
                'parents': [parent]
            },
            fields = "id, name, webViewLink, webContentLink",
        )
    )

async def update_doc(api, id, requests):
    return await api.as_service_account(
        docs.documents.batchUpdate(
            documentId = id,
            json = {
                "requests": requests
            }
        )
    )

def insert_image(uri, index):
    return {
        "insertInlineImage": {
            "uri": uri,
            "location": {
                "index": index
            },
            "objectSize": {
                "height": {
                    "magnitude": 125,
                    "unit": "PT"
                },
            }
        }
    }

async def main(parent_id, path, file, doc_id):
    async with client.api: # my "wrapper" around Aiogoogle
        folder = await create_folder(
            client.api,
            parent_id,
            "A folder in root folder"
        )
        image = await upload_file(
            client.api,
            f"{path}/{file}",
            folder["id"],
            "A file in created folder",
        )
        await update_doc(
            client.api,
            doc_id,
            [insert_image(image["webContentLink"], 0)]
        )
```

And while both the file and the folder were in fact created (it even says the account is the owner of them), I`m getting this error:

```
{'code': 400,
 'message': 'Invalid requests[0].insertInlineImage: Access to the provided '
            'image was forbidden.',
 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

I tried giving these arguments to both of drive.files.create() calls:

```py
includePermissionsForView = "published",
ignoreDefaultVisibility = True
```

, but no luck there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that when the image is put using `webContentLink` to Google Document using Docs API, the image is required to be publicly shared. So in your situation, how about the following patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `webContentLink` is used. Please publicly share the uploaded file using the method of "Permissions: create" in Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

By this, you can put the uploaded image using `webContentLink`. But in the current stage, there is the case that this link cannot be used. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150933939) I think that this might be a bug or the current specification.

So, as a workaround, I would like to propose another pattern.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `thumbnailLink` is used instead of `webContentLink` by modifying the query parameter. In this case, it is not required to publicly share the uploaded file.

Please add `thumbnailLink` to the fields like `fields = "id, name, webViewLink, webContentLink, thumbnailLink",` for `drive.files.create`. By this, `thumbnailLink` is included in the returned value. The value of `thumbnailLink` is as follows.

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/###=s220
```

Please modify `=s220` to `=s1000`. By this, the image size of the width of the image becomes large. Also, you can change this freely. And please use this modified URL to `insertInlineImage`.

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Comment: The issue I was having had been resolved by itself, so i guess there were some troubles at Google's side.
I really appreciate your answer though!

Comment: @Shmookoff Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: btw it looks like this issue pops up multiple times a day, so I think I`m gonna stick with your solution. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the first thing I've seen that actually work. It's a hack but it works. THANKS so much @Tanaike

Comment: @Marcus Hammarberg Thank you for your comment and for testing it. I'm glad for it. Thank you, too.